# search local directory using html file api and javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am planning to create an app using html5 file api and javascript to take directory path as input and be able to process (search for a text) all files in that directory and sub directories.

currently I am doing it using batchscript, What are constraints/obstacles doing it using HTML/javascript.

Comment: The HTML 5 File API can't take a directory path as input…

Comment: are you searching file names or file contents? use `<input type=file webkitdirectory multiple>` to get a whole folder into browser JS.

Answer (score 3):

In short: You can't to that automatically.

Access the local filesystem from any browser is blocked for security reasons. Reason: Imagine any website being able to access the files on your filesystem.

Read this: [Local file access with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371875/local-file-access-with-javascript)

Maybe you want to rephrase your question and say what you actually want to acheive.

You can access simple file information using the user's input and using `<input type=file>`.  But the user would require to do the following steps:

1. Click the "Browse button" (a file dialogue appears).
2. Navigate to the requested folder.
3. Select 1 or many files.
4. Click "Open".

Mozilla has documented this well with an example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications#Example_Showing_file(s)_size

Comment: user can can opt-in to allow file access using an `<input type=file>`

Comment: It is possible to read local directories [using the Filesystem API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51150691/975097) in client-side JavaScript.